# I have an iPad app that keeps getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

The first button displays a list of presidents and when you click on them you get their wikipedia page.  All worked well until I put in another button that let you change the language of the page from English to German, etc.  I keep getting this error in the debugger:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-04-30 17:30:01.293 Presidents[11151:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:

I'm going through a book tutorial and I think once again they are missing code. Any ideas would be awesome!

EDIT: Noob move on me guys I pasted the wrong code section: This new section is a custom popover that I added after the BIDMasterViewController, which was working fine.  This new section is where the problems arrived:

```
   #import "BIDLanguageListController.h"
#import "BIDDetailViewController.h"

@interface BIDLanguageListController ()

@end

@implementation BIDLanguageListController

@synthesize languageNames;
@synthesize languageCodes;
@synthesize detailViewController;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.languageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"English", @"French",
                          @"German", @"Spanish", nil];
    self.languageCodes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"fr", @"de", @"es", nil];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, [self.languageCodes count] * 44.0);

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.detailViewController = nil;
    self.languageNames = nil;
    self.languageCodes = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.languageCodes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [languageNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   detailViewController.languageString = [self.languageCodes objectAtIndex:
                                          [indexPath row]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Removed the 'compiler-error' tag, as this is obviously a runtime error...

Comment: It looks like you're returning a UITableViewCell... Could it be that your cell is nil?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224316/uitableview-datasource-must-return-a-cell-from-tableviewcellforrowatindexpath)

Comment: Similar to what @CodaFi said, add some logging or a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to make sure that it is not returning nil.

Comment: Edited with the correct section of code.  Again sorry guys, embarrassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never actually instantiating the cell!  There's so much good documentation around the web on how to reuse UITableViewCells.

Apple's Table View Programming Guide is amazing and definitely a must read:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

In the meantime, for a quick fix, change your method to something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART YOU ARE MISSING
    if(cell == nil) {
        //AND IF YOU PUT AN NSLOG IN HERE, YOU'LL SEE THIS IS CALLED ABOUT THE
        //NUMBER OF TIMES FOR THE INITIALLY VISIBLE CELLS ON THE SCREEN, PLUS 1 OR 2
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [languageNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Right on! Worked perfectly....I don't understand why this book would leave out such a small, but important part of code.  I'm just starting out and it gets annoying when these tutorials have errors in them.  Thankful for this site and it's helpful people. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate a UITableViewCell if one cannot be dequeued from your UITableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [languageNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for your quick, accurate response!

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that Xcode's templates make the same mistake as the tutorial referred to, I decided to investigate a bit further and came to a different conclusion. The problem is not in the instantiation of the cell, but in the cellIdentifier. The problem occurs when one changes the cellIdentifier in either the .xib *or* in the class, but not in both. 
When the .xib is loaded the first time, apparently the cell is queued with the identifier specified in the .xib. Then, when the code is run, the cell can always be dequeued, unless the code insists on a different cellIdentifier such as @"Cell". Checking whether the cell is nil and instantiating the cell rather defeats the purpose of a reusable cell. 
So, my answer is, strip out all  `if(cell == nil)` statements and check your cell identifiers instead.

Comment: I'm using Storyboard. I beleive i have done it in both. How would I go about checking my cell identifiers?

Comment: Select the cell in Interface Builder and look at the value in identifier field in the Attributes Inspector. Is it the same as the value specified in code, i.e. static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; ?