# How can i use prototype cell in storyboard with search result controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard, uisearchresultscontroller

I have `tableview` with search result controller when search in search bar get this error indicate that there is no cell and get the below error .How can create my `prototype` cell in this method `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

Code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HoCell";
Ho *cell;
Ho *item;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[Ho alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"HoCell"];
    }
    item = [searchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else{
    cell = (Ho*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    item = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
cell.ho.text = item.name;

cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"se.png"]];

return cell;
}
```

Error :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],  /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:5471
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be two possibilities Here :

> 1) You are returning a number larger than your Array Count from
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:. Don't.
>
> 2) One or more of your cell# outlets is not hooked up in your nib, or
>   is not hooked up to a UITableViewCell (or subclass). Hook them up
>   properly.

Go through this **Ray Wenderlich's Link :**
[How to Add Search Into a Table View](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=4512&start=40)

Check this **SO Questions :**

**1)** [UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224316/uitableview-datasource-must-return-a-cell-from-tableviewcellforrowatindexpath)

**2)** [ios 5 UISearchDisplayController crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066668/ios-5-uisearchdisplaycontroller-crash)

One More Beautiful Link : [Custom Prototype Table Cells and Storyboards](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/07/prototype-table-cells-and-storyboards.html) Just see this **Portion :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UYLCountryCellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    [self.countryCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = self.countryCell;
    self.countryCell = nil;
  }
  // Code omitted to configure the cell...
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: I use storyboard with prototype cell and make custom class for prototype cell called (Ho) , and check there no problem with number of rows in section.I investigate that the problem in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Just go through this Link : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/09/06/search-bar-table-view-storyboard.html

Comment: Thanks Bhavin but still used the standard prototype cell what about if i used custom class for prototype cell.

Comment: Ok.. I have added one more link in My Answer. Just Check it and let me know if your problem is solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be buggy. You check for cell == nil while it is not set to nil initially. It also looks a bit strange that you allocate your cells in that way based on search mode.

Anyways, I would do it different way. Imho the way I do it is almost canonical :) Just use your search result to populate your cells with correct data for each case (search mode and normal mode). In this example, searchResult and dataSource are arrays with strings. I think in real life for you it will be something more complex like array of nsdictionary.

In your view controller:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)_section
{
        /* Use correct data array so that in search mode we draw cells correctly. */
        NSMutableArray *data = searching ? searchResult : dataSource;
        return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
        /* Use correct data array so that in search mode we draw cells correctly. */
        NSMutableArray *data = searching ? searchResult : dataSource;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellId";

        CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        /* Note this is only correct for the case that you have one section */
        NSString *text = [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]

        cell.textLabel.text = text;
        /* More setup for the cell. */
        return text;
}
```

And here are delegate methods for search controller and some helpers:

```
- (void) searchTableView
{
        NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

        for (NSString *item in dataSource) {
                NSRange range = [item rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if (range.length > 0) {
                        [searchResult addObject:item];
                }
        }
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
        searching = NO;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
        searching = NO;
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [searchResult removeAllObjects];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchText
{
        [searchResult removeAllObjects];

        if ([searchText length] > 0) {
                searching = YES;
                [self searchTableView];
        } else {
                searching = NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try it didn't get me crash but table view is empty can't see data !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, here is what is did and it is now working perfectly..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Here is my code BEFORE
    //
    OPUsersTableViewCell *tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCellID];

    // Here is my code AFTER
    //
    OPUsersTableViewCell *tableCell = [self.groupTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCellID];
```

Note:

`self.groupTableView` is where the `prototype cell` is...